# Scheduled reminders not being sent

Tags: civimember, scheduled-reminders

All,

Scheduled reminders worked last year, but are not working this year.

I had made some changes to the Outbound Mail settings, but a) I set these back as they were and b) test emails come through just fine.

To sidestep the issue of 'day before membership end date', I entered today's date. When I manually executed 'Send Scheduled Reminders', the system reported that the job had completed, but no emails were sent and no errors were logged.

I just learned that things are not quite as 'simple' as I had hoped: At least one person received the reminder that I manually sent, but at least one person did not. I am among the 'at least one who did not' and I know that there are absolutely no email filters on the recipient side - so what happened?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the version of CiviCRM you are on.

Answer (score 2):

In v4.4 and v4.5 there is a known problem with membership reminders. Only one reminder email of each type will ever be sent to each member, not one each year, just one for that member forever. (Unless you have repeat turned on, but I think that is unlikely for membership renewal reminders as that creates another set of problems.)

It means you need to create copies of your existing reminders every 12 months (assuming you have one year memberships).

Things are different in [v4.6](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-15605), so if you are on v4.6 this answer will be irrelevant for you.

Comment: If you have used 4.4 or 4.5 and upgraded to 4.6 or 4.7, this answer can still be relevant. members that received renewal reminders before the update may still not receive the same reminders again after the upgrade, for example. I have not seen a simple solution for that, to date.

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be at two places, either some reminders aren't sent, or they are sent but get lost before reaching your inbox

It would be super useful to see the log of your mail server (the one that sends the emails for your civicrm), to be sure if civicrm has tried to send it or not.

If you have changed your mail settings, it's possible that your new configuration isn't properly tuned and that some of civi mails got caught by some spam filter along the way.